# Why schema is required while creating a table and not while querying a table - SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm new to the MS SQL server. Our client has given us a SQL server DB and for this DB they have configured the Service Principal Authentication. So I logged into the DB using my client company account and then I tried to create a table without giving any schema name. for example

```
CREATE TABLE visits (
    visit_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    first_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    visited_at DATETIME,
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    store_id INT NOT NULL,
);
```

so when I ran this query it gave me the below error

```
Msg 2760, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The specified schema name "aashay.amballi@<company>.com" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.
```

so now when I created the table with DBO schema it created the table.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.visits (
    visit_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    first_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    last_name VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    visited_at DATETIME,
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    store_id INT NOT NULL,
);
```

So now when I tried to query this visits table without any schema (i.e. DBO) `select * from visits` it actually gave me the result.

Also when I ran the `select SCHEMA_NAME()` to check what is the default schema, it returned null. So is there a possibility that when there is no default schema that is set for a user and while creating a table without a schema name it will give that error? if that is the case then while querying without any schema how it's picking the dbo schema by default?

So I'm a bit confused about how this is working. Can anyone please explain this?

This question is regarding the question that I asked a couple of days back when I'm trying to integrate MSSQL with service principal authentication with the Django Framework - [Django MigrationSchemaMissing exception on Azure SQL using service principal auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74742630/django-migrationschemamissing-exception-on-azure-sql-using-service-principal-aut)

Answer (score 2):

From the [CREATE TABLE description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#-type_schema_name--type_name):

> If type_schema_name isn't specified, the SQL Server Database Engine
> references type_name in the following order:
>
> - The SQL Server system data type.
> - The default schema of the current user in the current database.
> - The dbo schema in the current database.

And what is your default schema? It depends on options of [CREATE USER statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#with-default_schema--schema_name) used when creating your user's account:

> WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schema_name Specifies the first schema that will
> be searched by the server when it resolves the names of objects for
> this database user.

You can skip the schema in queries, but it is a best practise to [always use schemas](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/05/why-use-schemas/).

Comment: so in MS SQL can a user be created without a default schema? if yes then while creating a table shouldn't SQL Server Database Engine refer to dbo schema in the current database if it's not able to find the SQL server system data type + the default schema of the current user in the current DB?

Comment: No, user always has a default schema. The admin can select it CREATING the user, or can leave it with defaults. When QUERYING, without an explicit schema, SQL Server first looks under the schema associated with your login as default, then it looks under dbo schema. https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix

Comment: okay, but in my case, I logged in through service principal authentication to our DB.  When I tried to create a table without any schema defining it, it gave me an error. so even the service principal users will have default schema assigned to them?

Comment: As documentation says, there is always a schema. I quess, in your case, you need to use dbo schema, because your user has no other schema (that's a part of the error message). Lucky you - this is a better pattern in the end of the day ;-)

Comment: cool.. thank you for making me understand this.